# Android MediaPlayer setVolume not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Following is my code:

mp!!.setVolume(0.01f, 0.0f)

I am using Android MediaPlayer. Though I have set the volume of right to 0.0f, I am still able to hear from the right side. Is there any solution?

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
//class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
    var mp: MediaPlayer? = null;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.s2stereo);

        //this.mp = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.s1);

        try {
            //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3
            //mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/Music/maine.mp3")
            mp!!.prepare()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        // Do something in response to button click

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Javatpoint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        //mp!!.prepare()
        mp!!.start();
        mp!!.setVolume(0.01f, 0.0f)
    }

    fun sendMessage2(view: View) {
        // Do something in response to button click

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Javatpoint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        mp!!.pause();
        mp!!.seekTo(0);
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp!!.release()
            mp = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code, please!

Comment: added the code.